# copyrights in papertex

Tags: indexing

The package papertex.sty includes a copyright notice for nachollopis in every footer. This is not configurable with package arguments
I would like to change or eliminate this, thus I would have to modify the package
Is this legal according to the LPPL (the license of the package)? What would I have to do to ensure the legality of my actions?

Comment: You don't have to modify the package, you just have to *renew* the commands, which are described in section 5.2 (paperTEX default style) of the manual, in your own document. I.e. you write your own style.

Comment: what shoud i change in this   :  \newcommand{\papertex@footleft}{%
 {\footnotesize\copyright\ \papertex@wwwTxt{} - Created using \TeX{}}%
 }

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
\foot{}{}{}
```

to your document preamble.

The arguments define, respectively, what's in the left, center and right fields of the footer, the default is having in the left field the copyright notice. You can set the footer fields to whatever you like.

Using the given example, which I just report the start of,

```
\documentclass[10pt,final,hyphenatedtitles]{papertex}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ulem}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{times}

\foot{}{}{}
```

The rest of the document follows. Here is the bottom left of page 2.

[image]

Comment: tanks a lot sir

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own little paperTeX style package, let's call it: `mypapertexstyle.sty`. It should live in the same directory as your main document file, and it should contain all the commands you want to change, section 5.2 (paperTEX default style) of the manual gives a nice overview over what you can do. Just *renew* the commands you find there with thew value you need.

If you want to delete the copyright footer, this should suffice:

```
\renewcommand{\papertex@footleft}{}
```

All you have to do is load `mypapertexstyle.sty` in your main document by adding the package to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{mypapertexstyle}
```

This gives you the advantage to edit the style (colors, strings, fonts, etc) of your newspaper in one place so you can reuse it easily for new issues.